# How to create collection of different types of forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

is it possible to embed dynamically different types of forms to a single collection?

Let say I have a document (using ODM) with some embedded documents. These document I need to take and create a separate form for them. Up to this point it is OK. But how can I put them in the collection type of form, so I can be able to perform auto add and delete action of form?

Or I can do it manually, no problem, but where can I put my code? After calling bindRequest on the form? Is there a chance to remove deleted items from the form, because there is a possibility that I would not pass the isValid method.

And what I have learned so far that there is no way how to modified the form after it is created. I have an abstract form builder to which I'm adding these embedded documents. It is not a collection but separate forms, because each document has it's own form type. Is it correct approach or am I wrong?

Thanks for any correction or advice

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would create the forms for all of your embedded documents and then add those as collections to a "parent" form for your document. In that way, your top level form becomes the "collection" which you would then get the embedded data from.

So if your document is `A`:

```
class AType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->add('b', 'collection', [
            'type' => new BType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ])->add('c', 'collection', [
            'type' => new CType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ])->add('d', 'collection', [
            'type' => new DType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Forms are effectively just interactive views for your data model so this sounds like the way forward unless there's something stopping you from doing it this way?

Comment: I've adapted your solution and it almost works, but then the last level children I'm trying to add to the collections are marked as unresolved.

Comment: I'm not sure what "marked as unresolved" means in this context - are the fields not being populated?